# Is it possible to ask dependabot to ignore updates that requires a certain .NET version?

Tags: .net, nuget, dependabot

My team has started using dependabot to update our Nuget packages on a regular basis. Currently we have .NET 5.0, and  a lot of the PRs generated by dependabot includes major updates which is dependant on .NET 6.0. Per now I have added "ignore" in the dependabot.yml file for each dependency that has a major version update which is dependant on .NET 6.0 like this:

```
ignore:
        - dependency-name: "Castle.Core"
          update-types: ["version-update:semver-major"]
        - dependency-name: "Castle.Windsor"
          update-types: ["version-update:semver-major"]
```

However, there are a lot of PRs with suggested updates which I will have to ignore. Is it possible to somehow say "ignore all updates which are dependant on .NET 6.0"?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of specifying the ignore rule for each individual package, you can use the "match ("*") attribute to define a pattern that matches all packages with a .NET 6.0 dependency.

```
ignore:
  - dependency-name: "*"
    update-types: ["version-update:semver-major"]
    versions: ["<6.0"]
```

Comment: But how does it know that it is .NET 6.0 that should be ignored, and not for instance Castle.Core 6.0 or similar if .NET is never specified?